# Derived contract not selected by defaut on remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I have two simple contracts, a base one (BaseClass.sol):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

abstract contract BaseContract {
    
    address private immutable wallet;
    
    constructor(address _wallet) {

        require(_wallet != address(0), "address not set");

        wallet = _wallet;
    }    
}
```

And a contract that derives from the base one by passing the wallet address on the constructor (DerivedClass.sol):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "./BaseClass.sol";

contract DerivedContract
    is BaseContract(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) {
        
    constructor() {}
}
```

Everything works but on remix the default selected contract is always BaseContract, not DerivedContract.

[image]

This is cumbersome because I need to keep needing to switch back to DerivedContract when deploying.

Any way to have DerivedContract set as the default contract when compiling it?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears they are sorted by alphabetical order.

Comment: @Ismael doesn't seem so, I renamed DerivedContract to ADerivedContract and the order remained the same.

Comment: It seems to be sorted by the file's name and within the same file contract by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the current version sort contracts by the file's name and within the same file contracts are sorted by name.

```
- Welcome to Remix 0.10.10 -
```